# undefined field store_id on catalog search reindex, magento 2 with solr search

Tags: solr, magento2

I have configured solr-4.10.4 with Magento 2.0.2 and tested the connection. The Connection is successful, but when I tried to reindex, I am getting the "undefined field store_id" exception:

[image: screen shot of command prompt with solr exception]

Comment: can you share the schema.xml...? you must be missing the entry for store_id in it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue on Solr end but catalog search configuration on magento end.

The error means magento is trying to reindex "store_id" field but it couldn't find "store_id" on schema.xml file. In other words, you should explicitly define Solr Server Path on Magento-admin-Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Catalog Search. Instead of defining Solr server path as just "solr" , you should define as "solr/magento2" where magento2 is your solr collection defined on solr. This happens when you have multiple collections as it takes default collection when not defined explicitly.

And, collection name isn't checked when connection is tested. A connection test is merely connecting to solr server with IP and port provided. So, successful connection doesn't necessarily guarantee that search works.